# Setting ID for Ember.TextFiled

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am facing an issue of setting the id in Ember.Textfield. We have a model class which extends from Em.Object.

I am trying to access it in HBS(Handlebars) through the controller like this `ViewData.id.id1` in Ember TextField.  But the model is not setting the id.

```
 {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="value" id=ViewData.id.id1}}
```

I am using the following library for Ember and handlebars:

```
 (handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js)
 (ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.min.js)
```

We have code like this:

```
 Em.ObjectController.extend({
     ViewData : data.create()
 });
 var data = Em.Object.extend({
     id: {
         id1: "textId1",
     },
 });
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? Kindly assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to put it in quotes? id="ViewData.id.id1"

Comment: If this does not fix, i guess you have to use a Binding -> id="ViewData.id.id1"

Answer (score 3):

You can set a view'd `id` attribute with the `elementId` property:

```
{{view Ember.TextField elementId="foobar"}}
```

Unfortunately, this can't be a computed property or binding. The following won't work:

```
{{view Ember.TextField elementIdBinding="id.id1"}}
```

Nor will this:

```
var TextFieldWithID = Ember.TextField.extend({
  elementId: function() {
    return this.get('controller.id.id1');
  }.property('controller.id.id1')
});

{{view TextFieldWithID}}
```

The problem is that Ember needs a unique, stable ID when the element is created so it can set up bindings. By making the `elementId` property a binding or computed property, you're saying it can change. Ember then just ignores the property and generates a unique ID of its own.

Answer (score 0):

The elementIdBinding works.

We need to reopen the Ember.TextField with the attributeBindings like this

Ember.TextField.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['elementId']
});

The hbs will have the following code.

{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="data" elementIdBinding="ViewData.id.id1"}}

It works !!!!

Cheers!!